# Why isn't Google Maps' Custom Overlay working? (In their docs)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently trying to implement Custom Overlays and am looking at Google's docs. However, their example doesn't seem to be working which is making it quite difficult.

Docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

It appears that the "onAdd" callback is never called, even though [these docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view) say that onAdd will be called after setMap is called.

Anyone know what's wrong with their example and why it's not working?

Comment: They broke it when the translated it to the new format.  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/sqcaxb1n/1/).  The pieces that depend on the API need to be in the `initMap` function.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks! Feel free to submit as an answer if you want me to accept it (I don't think I can accept a comment as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

**geocodezip** commented and their answer fixes it :).

"They broke it when the translated it to the new format. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/sqcaxb1n/1/). The pieces that depend on the API need to be in the initMap function"

See below for fiddle contents:

```
(function(exports) {
  "use strict";

  // This example creates a custom overlay called USGSOverlay, containing
  // a U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) image of the relevant area on the map.
  // Set the custom overlay object's prototype to a new instance
  // of OverlayView. In effect, this will subclass the overlay class therefore
  // it's simpler to load the API synchronously, using
  // google.maps.event.addDomListener().
  // Note that we set the prototype to an instance, rather than the
  // parent class itself, because we do not wish to modify the parent class.
  // Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

  function initMap() {
    USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: {
        lat: 62.323907,
        lng: -150.109291
      },
      mapTypeId: "satellite"
    });
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132),
      new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608)
    ); // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.

    var srcImage =
      "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/" +
      "javascript/examples/full/images/talkeetna.png"; // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
    // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
  /** @constructor */

  function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {
    // Initialize all properties.
    this.bounds_ = bounds;
    this.image_ = image;
    this.map_ = map; // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
    // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
    // method so we'll leave it null for now.

    this.div_ = null; // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.

    this.setMap(map);
  }
  /**
   * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
   * added to the map.
   */

  USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.borderStyle = "none";
    div.style.borderWidth = "0px";
    div.style.position = "absolute"; // Create the img element and attach it to the div.

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    console.log(this.image_);
    img.src = this.image_;
    img.style.width = "100%";
    img.style.height = "100%";
    img.style.position = "absolute";
    div.appendChild(img);
    this.div_ = div; // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.

    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
  };

  USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
    // We use the south-west and north-east
    // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
    // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection(); // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
    // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
    // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.

    var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(
      this.bounds_.getSouthWest()
    );
    var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(
      this.bounds_.getNorthEast()
    ); // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.

    var div = this.div_;
    div.style.left = sw.x + "px";
    div.style.top = ne.y + "px";
    div.style.width = ne.x - sw.x + "px";
    div.style.height = sw.y - ne.y + "px";
  }; // The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
  // we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.

  USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
  };
    exports.overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
      exports.USGSOverlay = USGSOverlay;

  }


  exports.initMap = initMap;
})((this.window = this.window || {}));
```